# is my javascript secure

Tags: java, javascript, model-view-controller

How much some one can modify a javascript to intercept the post parameters to hack or missplay

```
 function search(tableEvent)
        {
            clearResults()
            document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
            var params = 'formAction=SearchInterviewNomineesCent';
            params += '&reqNo=${param.reqNo}';
            params += '&reqSeq=${param.reqSeq}';
            params += '&reqClass=${param.reqClass}';
            params += '&reqYear=${param.reqYear}';
            params += '&relatedReqYear=${param.relatedReqYear}';
            params += '&relatedReqSeq=${param.relatedReqSeq}';
            params += '&relatedReqNo=${param.relatedReqNo}';
            params += '&relatedReqClass=${param.relatedReqClass}';
            params += '&tableEvent=' + tableEvent;
            createXmlHttpObject();
            sendRequestPost(http_request,'Controller',false,params);

            prepareUpdateTableContents();

        }
```

am using JAVA MVC and am curious can some one edit javascript for the above code to get a different search result by modify search criteria like reqNo and reqSeq

UPDATE:
i mean here an organization with local network , so the attack would be from some employee who has access to system

Comment: No, it's not secure. You need to verify the HTTPRequest on your server.Anyone can make a loop, change the text or modify the code through Firebug or any other tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all anyone can edit any javascript you see in the browser.  They can manipulate values and what it sends to the server.  Furthermore they could simply write their own code to post to your url.  It isn't in the client side that you will make your system secure but on the server side.

Comment: how on server side i can make it secure this big system has privileges for some group id check on every request but what if you have privilege and want to get another data or do operation to someone is this enough

Comment: i accepted it because you answered its not secure as i asked but could be kind to answer how to make it secure on server side for MVC web app so anyone view this question get help too

Comment: I was offline for a bit, how to make it secure on the server side is a very big question... normally you will want to verify the person though some sort of password and identification and when this happens you can hand them a session (which may or may not time out).  Every time they want to do something they have to hand you the session to show that they have permission to do it.  Other things to watch out for is to make sure if the same url is hit many times with the same data you normally want the property of [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) to prevent data corruption.

Comment: nice i have these but not Idempotence its kind of new to me thanks i will google it